# Compute this double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Compute the integral
$$
\iint_{S}\sin\left(\,y - x \over x + y\,\right)\,{\rm d}A
$$
 where S is the trapezoidal region of the plane bounded by the lines
$x + y = 1$, $x + y = 2$ and the coordiante axis.

So when I just computed as normal way and I found out by software that the integral of $\sin\left(\,y - x \over x + y\right)$ is some crazy expression.
So I think there should be some other way to solve this question, is it something related to change of coordinate ? If yes, how?

Comment: Use a change of coordinates to make the symmetry more apparent.

Comment: can you show me a little bit how to do it?

Comment: Take $u = y-x;\; v = y+x$. Find out which region in the $uv$-plane $S$ becomes.

Comment: thanks, one more question, what will be the boundary then. I know v=1 and v=2, how about u?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
If you exchange $x$ with $y$ the integral changes its sign.
The result is $\color{#00f}{\Large\mbox{zero}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Is for change of coordinates. Write $u=y-x$ and $v=x+y$. Then $y=\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{1}{2}v$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}v-\frac{1}{2}u$. Now, we must transform the region in the $xy$ plane in a region of the plane $uv$ as follow: Let be $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ the transform
$$T(x,y)=(y-x, x+y):=(u,v). $$
This transform send  the trapezoidal region $S$ on $xy$ plan in the region in $uv$ plan with coordinates $(-1,1); (1,1); (2,2)$ and $(-2,2)$ (make a drawing).

The determinant of Jacobian transformation is
$$\det\frac{J(x,y)}{(u,v)}= -\frac{1}{2},$$
Then,
$$\int\int_S \sin (\frac{y-x}{x+y})dA=\int_{v=1}^{v=2}\int_{u=-v}^{u=v}\sin \left(\frac{u}{v} \right)\cdot \left|-\frac{1}{2}\right|dudv=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{v=1}^{v=2}\left( v\int_{u=-v}^{u=v}\sin\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)\frac{1}{v}du \right)dv =... =0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u = -x + y$, and $v = x + y$. Then $y = \frac{u + v}2$, and $x = \frac{v - u}2$. Now we need to find the region in the $uv$-plane.

$$x + y = 1 \implies v = 1.$$

$$x + y = 2 \implies v = 2.$$

$$y = 0\ \text{(}x\text{-axis in }xy\text{-plane)} \implies u + v = 0 \implies u = -v.$$

$$x = 0\ \text{(}y\text{-axis in }xy\text{-plane)} \implies v - u = 0 \implies u = v.$$

Thus the region $S'$ in the $uv$-plane is also a trapezoid and is bounded by the lines:

$$u = v, u = -v, v = 1,\text{ and }v = 2.$$

So the set up for the new integral is:

$$\int_1^2\int_{-v}^v -\frac12\sin\left(\!\frac uv\!\right)\,du\,dv.$$

You can continue.